# Add to windows firewall exception in standard user

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I am trying to add an application to windows firewall exception.
I don’t want to give admin privileges to the EXE.

I tried netsh command as below.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Myapp" dir=in action=allow program=”C:\Program files\app.exe "
```

But this requires administrative privilege.

Is there any ways to add to firewall exception without admin previleges?

I think it is possible because I have one Application which does so.

I am using Talley ERP 9 which adds itself to firewall exception without admin privileges. When I run Talley it pops up with a message as shown below.

[image]

If I click on either of options (‘Allow access’ or ‘Cancel’) the Tally will be added to firewall exception. This works in both Administrator and Non-Administrator users.

I have tracked the changes made by that exe and found that there are values added in to the registry key,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules
```

How tally ERP 9 is able to add firewall exception without having admin privileges?

I couldn’t find any manifest file in tally ERP 9 path also.